# New text field is overlapped while implementing select2 using Bootstrap and jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using the `select2` plugin for autosuggestion using jQuery but it's adding one new text field over the existing one. I am providing my code below.

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
   <div class="">
      <label class="control-label go-right">Select City</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="currentlocationlist" class="form-control">
</div>


$("#currentlocationlist").select2({
          placeholder:'Enter location name',
          minimumInputLength: 3,
          width:'100%',
          maximumSelectionSize: 1,
          initSelection:function(element, callback){
            var data = {id: "1", text: " "};
            callback(data);
          },
          ajax:{
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/ajaxcalls/locationsList",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: function (term, page) {
              return {
                query: term, // search term
              };
            },
            results: function (data, page) {
              return {results: data};
            }
          }
        })
        $("#currentlocationlist").on("select2-selecting", function(e) {
          $("#currentlocationlist").val(e.val);
        });
```

Here all are working as expected but one new text field is overlapping over existing one and the screen shot is given below.

[image]

Here I need to merge both text field in one.

Answer (score 0):

Take out the class `form-control` applied to the `<input>` tag and it'll work fine.

**Snippet with `form-control` class:**

```js
$('#currentlocationlist').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Click here",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Ford"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Dodge"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Mercedes" },
            { id: 4, text: "Jaguar"   }
          ]    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
   <div class="">
      <label class="control-label go-right">Select City</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="currentlocationlist" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**And here's a snippet *without* the `form-control`:**

```js
$('#currentlocationlist').select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: true,
    multiple: true,
    maximumSelectionSize: 1,
    placeholder: "Click here",
    data: [
            { id: 1, text: "Ford"     },
            { id: 2, text: "Dodge"    },
            { id: 3, text: "Mercedes" },
            { id: 4, text: "Jaguar"   }
          ]    
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/select2/3.4.8/select2.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-3 form-group">
   <div class="">
      <label class="control-label go-right">Select City</label>
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="currentlocationlist" class="">
</div>
```

This is because the **classes** that you assign to the element that you're going to initialize `select2` with get added to the select2-container that's rendered within the select2 lib due to which the Bootstrap CSS for `form-control` gets applied and hence the mess. Hope this helps.